# How to show this equality of $\mu$

Tags: probability, statistics

since we know that X and Y are independent, then the pair $(XY^c)$, $(X^cY)$, $(X^cY^c)$ also independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1)\quad \mu(XY^c)=\mu(X)-\mu(XY).$$
$$(2)\quad \mu(X^c Y)=\mu(Y)-\mu(XY).$$
$$(3)\quad\mu(X^c Y^c)=\mu(Y^c)-\mu(XY^c)=1-\mu(Y)-\mu(XY^c)=1-\mu(Y)-\mu(X)+\mu(XY),$$
using (1). Now, putting these together,
\begin{align*}
&\,\mu(XY)\mu(X^c Y^c)-\mu(XY^c)\mu(X^cY)\\
=&\,\mu(XY)\left(1-\mu(Y)-\mu(X)+\mu(XY)\right)-\left(\mu(X)-\mu(XY)\right)\left(\mu(Y)-\mu(XY)\right)\\
=&\,\mu(XY)-\mu(XY)\mu(Y)-\mu(XY)\mu(X)+\mu(XY)^2-\mu(X)\mu(Y)+\mu(X)\mu(XY)+\mu(Y)\mu(XY)-\mu(XY)^2\\
=&\,\mu(XY)-\mu(X)\mu(Y).\quad\blacksquare
\end{align*}